# Prove that if there is 44$ bill and 10 people to split the bill, then at least two people paid the same amount of money.

Tags: logic, pigeonhole-principle

I'm learning how to do proofs and now trying to prove the following statement:

> Suppose you are having dinner with nine friends and want to split the bill, which is $44. Everyone pays in dollar bills. Prove that at least two people in your group paid the same amount of money.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to proceed. I though about cardinalities of a set which consists of people ($ \vert F\vert $) and a cardinality of a set consisting of payments ($ \vert P \vert $) that people did, so that $ \vert P \vert < \vert F\vert $, because at least two people pay the same amount of money. But it doesn't seem to help and I have no idea what else to try.

I'd be grateful for any hints you can provide.

Comment: Hint: what is the least possible total amount, if everybody pays a different amount?

Comment: @TonyK Took the words out of my mouth.

Comment: @TonyK, okay, I got it. You mean that the least possible amount will be when each of them pays the minimum number, but different than the previous one, so starting from 1, 2, ... and ending with 10. In this case total amount will be equal to 55. It's the least possible amount and it's greater than 44. Have I got that right?

Comment: Not quite.  Some deadbeat might pay $0$.

Comment: @saulspatz Ah yeah, you're right. In that case total will be equal to 45 which is also greater than 44, so it's much clearer now why the author took 44 for the problem :) Thank you very much. You're so clever guys!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose no 2 paid the same; let the amounts paid be $p_1,p_2,..,p_{10}$ in increasing order. Then $p_1\ge 0,\; p_2\ge 1+p_1\ge 1,\; p_3\ge 1+p_2\ge 2,$ etc. So $p_1+p_2+p_3+...+p_{10}\ge 0+1+2+...+9=45.$ But the total is $44.$